# Android editing Drawable and setting it to ImageView in another activity

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, drawable

I have a method plotPoints(float x, float y) that I would like to use to plot a point on a drawable. I attempt to add a point to the drawable using a bitmap and canvas. Then, depending on whether plotPoints() has been called, I either set the the ImageView of a separate activity to the original drawable's bitmap (without the point), or the edited bitmap with the point. However, the ImageView always displays the original drawable, it never shows the drawn point. Please let me know if you can help.

Here is the related code:

```
Bitmap labBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.lab_image);
```

plotPoints() method:

```
    public void plotPoints(float x, float y) {
    pointsPlotted = true;

    //Paint for LocationActivity
    Paint labPaint = new Paint();
    labPaint.setColor(color.holo_purple);

    //Initialize tempBitmap and attach a new canvas to it    
    Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(labBitmap.getWidth(), labBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);

    //Draw the image Bitmap onto the Canvas
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(labBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    //Set paint Color and draw X and Y coordinates on Canvas
    tempCanvas.drawPoint(x, y, labPaint);
}
```

Here is where I decide which bitmap to use and start the new activity:

```
    public void openLabView() {
    //Compress bitmap for smoother pass to LocationActivity
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] b;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationActivity.class);

    if(pointsPlotted) {
        tempBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        b = baos.toByteArray();
        intent.putExtra("imageBitmap", b);
    }
    else {
        labBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        b = baos.toByteArray();
        intent.putExtra("imageBitmap", b);
    }

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And here is the onCreate() of the new activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    //Receive Bitmap for ImageView
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] b = extras.getByteArray("imageBitmap");

    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lab_image);

    image.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
}
```

Comment: I'd start trying to track this down by setting a breakpoint in openLabView() and running a couple of Debugs so you can inspect the contents of the ByteArray when pointsPlotted is true compared to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `plotPoints()` method, you define a `Bitmap tempBitmap` in that method's scope. So outside of that method (`openLabView()`) it has no reference to the `tempBitmap` from `plotPoints()` but maybe another same named `Bitmap` in the class scope. This might be a reason why the `Bitmap` generated in `openLabView()` doesn't seem to change.

May I suggest slightly renaming `Bitmap tempBitmap` in `plotPoints()` just for easier debugging, and see if that `Bitmap` inside `plotPoints()` can be passed to `openLabView()`, as that `Bitmap` should have been modified by the `Canvas`. (Basically the `Bitmap` passed to the `Canvas` constructor is what you want.)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried declaring tempBitmap (and renaming it) at the beginning of the class, so as not to limit the scope as you mentioned. Unfortunately, the Bitmap didn't change following a call to openLabView().

Comment: Ok another attempt, what if the Paint object doesnt have a pen size set? Try playing with `setStrokeWidth()` or even drawing rectangles to see if that makes a difference.

Or even try directly calling the intent code with the bitmap directly in the plotPoints() method to test

Comment: Got it! I messed around with a bunch of the Paint settings and eventually found a combination that worked. Thanks a lot for your help!